# Как сделать открытое модальное окно при входе на сайт?

Tags: javascript

Есть скрипт и он рабочий, окно открывается по кнопке, но нужно чтоб окно открывалось при входе на сайт.

```js
function openbox(id, tt) {
  var div = document.getElementById(id);
  var tt_div = document.getElementById(tt);
  if (div.style.display == 'block') {
    div.style.display = 'none';
  } else {
    div.style.display = 'block';
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="layer">
  <a href="#" onclick="openbox('Wrapp');return false;">Открыть</a>
</div>
<div id="Wrapp" style="display:none">
  <div id='tt'>
    <div class="close" onclick="openbox('Wrapp')">Закрыть</div>
    <div class="table"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предлагаю просто убрать из разметки :

```
 style="display:none"
```

и этот элемент не будет изначально спрятан...

——-

Answer (score 2):

После того как страница загрузится запустите функцию открытия окна:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){ 
  openbox('Wrapp');
});
```

Comment: плюс поставил, однако коль сколько это все сильно выдрано из контекста, я считаю что добавлять код в общем случае, всегда хуже, чем удалять его :)

Comment: Согласен, но возможно человеку открыть модальное окно нужно только при определённых условиях, поэтому написал таким образом :)